# Python GUI - Button Image is blank

Tags: python, user-interface, button

I'm developing a software in python where i need to create 2 buttons. I created this buttons with the same code, but the second one's image is blank, while the first isn't. This is the code:

```
picModificaClienti = PhotoImage(file='ModificaClienti.png')
ModificaClientiButton = Button(ClientiWindow, text='', image=picModificaClienti, width=150, height=60, command = ModificaClientiWindowF)
ModificaClientiButton.place(x=270, y=120)
picAnnullaClientiOP = PhotoImage(file = "AnnullaButton.png")
AnnullaClientiButton = Button(ClientiWindow, text='', image=picAnnullaClientiOP, width=150, height=60, command = ModificaClientiWindowF)
AnnullaClientiButton.place(x=480, y=120)
```

Comment: I presume this is TKinter?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: You didnt mention anywhere that this is TKinter.. Hence why I asked.

Comment: Yes i know, sorry. Didn't think of it